# Change email on old account

Tags: psn

My old profile has an email address I no longer have access to. How do I change it to my new email? When I've tried, it wants to send a verification to the nonexisting address.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is just one of those things you'll have to talk to Sony support about... I would imagine it's a reasonably common issue (college students using their college emails, then losing access to them, etc.).
I've had to contact Sony support a couple times to change different things (not email though) and it's typically pretty painless and easy.

You can try the live chat [here](https://scea.secure.force.com/PreChatEnglishForm/?endpoint=https%3A%2F%2Fscea.secure.force.com%2FLiveChat%2Fapex%2FLiveAgentChat%3Flanguage%3D%23deployment_id%3D572i00000002cba%26org_id%3D00Di0000000H5ef%26button_id%3D573i00000002ftp%26session_id%3D7b65b03c-4bb3-4b1a-a8a3-7d05878b63c7). (there's a picture of a PS4 on the page, but I don't think it's specifically a PS4 chat support)

Comment: Agreed, I have heard that this is possible by contacting customer support at Sony. Though you may have to call them for this one.